# Grouping based on measurement datetime continuity

Tags: r, datetime, grouping

My problem has to do with grouping measurements based on their continuity. 
Here is an example.

```
a=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-07-20 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-07-20 12:00:00"), by="30 min")
b=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-07-20 20:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-07-20 22:00:00"), by="30 min")
c=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-07-21 08:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-07-21 10:30:00"), by="30 min")
df= data.frame(date=c(a,b,c), conc=runif(15))
```

The desired output will look like this

```
 date       conc group
2014-07-20 10:00:00 0.30899449     x
2014-07-20 10:30:00 0.25436235     x
2014-07-20 11:00:00 0.01122904     x
2014-07-20 11:30:00 0.38944058     x
2014-07-20 12:00:00 0.26457760     x
2014-07-20 20:00:00 0.50039528     y
2014-07-20 20:30:00 0.72761115     y
2014-07-20 21:00:00 0.06544978     y
2014-07-20 21:30:00 0.01836020     y
2014-07-20 22:00:00 0.26401722     y
2014-07-21 08:30:00 0.51394754     z
2014-07-21 09:00:00 0.23298657     z
2014-07-21 09:30:00 0.27799685     z
2014-07-21 10:00:00 0.34541882     z
2014-07-21 10:30:00 0.08069711     z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df$group <- c("x", "y", "z")[cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(df$date)!=30))]
df$group
#[1] "x" "x" "x" "x" "x" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "z" "z" "z" "z" "z"
```

or

```
 df$group <- factor(cumsum(c(TRUE,df$date[-1]-df$date[-nrow(df)] >30)), 
                                                    labels=letters[24:26])
```

Comment: I dont know why the question has been downvoted. The above is just an example, the original data contains 100,000 records and many gaps in between them.

Comment: @Swagath You may want to clearly address your question so that more people can see your point. I could not understand your question till I saw akrun's answer. BTW, I didn't down vote.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will make it clear next time.

Comment: @akrun I can read the `cumsum` part in the first option. How does this work with the `c()` part? I guess whenever T and F changes, R assigns x, y, and z. Do you use this syntax often?

Comment: @Swagath As jazzurro mentioned, I was also a little confused about how you want to make the grouping until I saw how you constructed the data.  +1 to post more questions with clarity.

Comment: @jazzurro the `cumsum(..)` gets you a numeric index of `1:3` values.  So, we can use `c("x", "y", "z")` the `1s` gets replaced by `x`, `2 with y` and `3 with z`.  I guess that is what you asked.

Comment: @akrun Sorry, I was somehow thinking the `cumsum` parts returns T/F. This is a new way to replace elements for me. Thanks for the lesson as usual. +1.

Comment: @Swagath - click on "close" and you'll see why you got downvotes

Comment: @RichardScriven Can anyone still downvote my question even after I have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to `plyr` and `dplyr`, this would be one approach.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(group = cumsum(c(F, diff(date) > 30)),
           group = as.character(group),
           group = revalue(group, c("0" = "x", "1" = "y", "2" = "z")))

#                  date       conc group
#1  2014-07-20 10:00:00 0.74729551     x
#2  2014-07-20 10:30:00 0.93302377     x
#3  2014-07-20 11:00:00 0.63812335     x
#4  2014-07-20 11:30:00 0.07552563     x
#5  2014-07-20 12:00:00 0.92733773     x
#6  2014-07-20 20:00:00 0.01533538     y
#7  2014-07-20 20:30:00 0.47554703     y
#8  2014-07-20 21:00:00 0.65365968     y
#9  2014-07-20 21:30:00 0.87205291     y
#10 2014-07-20 22:00:00 0.34648272     y
#11 2014-07-21 08:30:00 0.03557178     z
#12 2014-07-21 09:00:00 0.37837235     z
#13 2014-07-21 09:30:00 0.29888315     z
#14 2014-07-21 10:00:00 0.90837697     z
#15 2014-07-21 10:30:00 0.61514152     z
```

Comment: Here, if you use `c(T, diff(date)..))` and then cumsum, you will get the index from `1:3` or else you can use `+1` and then substitute the letters x, y, z.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the advice. I will take a note of that as well as the `c()` thing.